# Cannot connect MoveIt with Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am new to ROS and trying to connect MoveIt with Gazebo simulation for a scara robot. I am facing with this particular error. I have created the urdf file and tuned all the joints accordingly.

> RLException: unused args
> [execution_type] for include of
> [/home/mrj/catkin_ws/src/scara_moveit_config/launch/scara_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml] The traceback for the exception was
> written to the log file

Below is my scara_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml file

```
<launch>
  <rosparam file="$(find scara_moveit_config)/config/controllers.yaml"/>
  <param name="use_controller_manager" value="false"/>
  <param name="trajectory_execution/execution_duration_monitoring" value="false"/>
  <param name="moveit_controller_manager" value="moveit_simple_controller_manager/MoveItSimpleControllerManager"/>
</launch>
```

Controllers.yaml

```
controller list:
  - name: arm_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - base_link_link_01
      - link_01_link_02
      - link_02_link_03
  
  - name: gripper_controller
    action_ns: follow_joint_trajectory
    type: FollowJointTrajectory
    joints:
      - link_03_link_04 </launch>
```

I had created a joints_names.yaml file to load in the parameter server

```
controller_joint_names: [base_link_link_01,link_01_link_02,link_02_link_03,link_03_link_04]
```

And this is the main planning_execution file I am running

```
<launch>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find scara_moveit_config)/config/joint_names.yaml"/>

    <include file="$(find scara_moveit_config)/launch/planning_context.launch">
        <arg name="load_robot_description" value="true"/>
    </include>

    <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
        <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
        <rosparam param="/source_list">[/joint_states]</rosparam>
    </node>

    <include file="$(find scara_moveit_config)/launch/move_group.launch">
        <arg name="publish_monitored_planning_scene" value="true"/>
    </include>
    
    <include file="$(find scara_moveit_config)/launch/moveit_rviz.launch">
        <arg name="config" value="true"/>
    </include>
</launch>
```

Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378891/cannot-connect-moveit-with-gazebo/) by [Samarth Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/75029/samarth-jain/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2021-05-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks to me like somewhere in your launch file inclusion chain you are passing an arg called `execution_type` to `scara_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml`, but that file does not have an argument called `execution_type` (as seen in the original question). The so-called "planning_execution" launch file provided in the original question `<include>`s  several launch files that could be the root cause (`planning_context.launch`, `move_group.launch`, and `moveit_rviz.launch`). Without seeing all of the launch files it's tough to know which one is the root cause. I'd suggest looking in your package for a launch file that uses an `<include>` tag with `scara_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml` that also has an `<arg name="execution_type" value="...." />` tag as a child. This is most likely where the error posted is coming from.

Note, I've occasionally found `rqt_launchtree` very useful for debugging issues like this: http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_launchtree

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2021-05-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Samarth Jain](https://answers.ros.org/users/75029/samarth-jain/) on 2021-05-25**:
Thank you for your suggestion. rqt_launchtree is not available for noetic as of now. Is there any alternative available for that?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2021-05-25**:
You could certainly building/running `rqt_launchtree` from source. It might work. You could also use the `--files` and `--dump-params` args to `roslaunch`. Although, it might just be easier to do a bit of work with grep to find where the `execution_type` arg shows up in your package. Something like `roslaunch <PATH_TO_PLANNING_EXECUTION_LAUNCH> | xargs grep execution_type -` would show you all launch files included and which ones had the phrase `execution_type` showing up. That would be a pretty good start

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've just met the same problem. The root cause is in the file trajectory_execution.launch.xml, the latest ROS version produces an extra line  in this file. Delete it and the gazebo && rviz

---

Originally posted by [FinleyGou](https://answers.ros.org/users/81206/finleygou/) with karma: 21 on 2021-08-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ckashis](https://answers.ros.org/users/86715/ckashis/) on 2021-10-08**:
Thank you. I also had the same issue. It occurred when I tried to launch `move_group.launch` from the MoveIt package. After deleting that line the error got solved.